# It was a maneuver to do; it was a maneuver doing; doing was a maneuver

Tags: vocabulary

Why is "It was a maneuver to participate in the annual soccer competition at school" wrong and "It was a thrill to participate in the annual soccer competition at school" right?

Wouldn't "Participating in the annual soccer competition at school was a maneuver" and "Participating in the annual soccer competition at school was a thrill" be right? If so, what about the first pair of sentences?

Comment: All the sentences work, but how was participating in soccer a maneuver? That would mean it took some trickery, or it was a special accomplishment like an athletic advancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically viable, but they mean different things and cannot be transformed in the way you appear to indicate.

In your first sentence ("it was a maneuver to participate..."), *maneuver* means "an action taken to gain a tactical end" or "a clever management of affairs often using trickery and deception"; the prepositional phrase "to participate" describes what the maneuver was intended to accomplish; and the subject "it" refers to some previous action.  To rephrase the sentence, "(somebody) did (some unspecified thing) with the goal of being allowed to participate in the soccer competition."

You cannot transform the sentence into "participating... was a maneuver"; that sentence means "(somebody) did (participate in the soccer tournament) with the goal of (accomplishing some unspecified thing)."

In your second sentence ("It was a thrill to participate"), *thrill* means a "a sudden strong feeling especially of excitement or happiness"; the prepositional phrase "to participate" describes what caused the thrill; and the subject "it" is a forward reference to the prepositional phrase.   This sentence CAN be transformed as you indicate without changing the meaning; we simply pull the subject (referenced by "it") forward, eliminating the need for the pronoun reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider *manoeuvre* as interchangeable with *movement*.

Is that by itself enough to remove the question?

Comment: Actually, your answer didn't help a lot. Check the one above, by @hellion. His detailed answer clarified all my doubts.

Comment: Tiago, Hellion's answer might well have clarified all your doubts.

You're welcome to limit your appreciation as much as you like and still, try asking most people whether they see the main and prolly think of the only meanings of  *manoeuvre* as a noun being *movement* and as a verb being *move*.